# Issues deploying monorepo containing Next.js + Express app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, next.js

I am following Ben Awad's wonderful [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6ypD7qv3Z8) to build a fullstack
app using Next.js, Express, Typescript, and GraphQL. Everything works smoothly locally, but I have run into a barrage of issues trying to deploy to Heroku. I would really like to deploy both server and client to Heroku as one app, and have Express serve the frontend files as well as be the backend.

```
monorepo
  - web
     - package.json
  - server
     - package.json
package.json
```

To my understanding, this is possible using Next's custom server option, which I have integrated in my server.js file. My problem is when deploying to Heroku, it doesn't detect React as a dependency for the backend so while the deploy succeeds, the app crashes when I try to access it in the browser. I have tried a few things to resolve this issue - having two copies of React in frontend and backend, respectively, only leads to more problems (understandably so). I have tried keeping one copy and using npm link to point to the module, but it only works locally. I've tried changing the webpack config as well but it doesn't seem to register. I tried defining the custom server as a util in the frontend and import it in server.js, but the import is always undefined, which makes sense so I moved it back.

I'm still new and have many misconceptions about how Next.js works, especially when coupled with a custom server, so I might be doing something fundamentally wrong. Is there anything I'm missing, or is it better to split the app into two Heroku apps and push one subtree into each?
The source code can be found [here](https://github.com/Baheya/reddit-clone), but I will be probably rolling back because it has become very messy.

I know there are other ways to do this I just don't want to give up quite yet.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? How can we get this more support/views? I'm in a very similar position as you are and there is no reliable documentation on how to push one repo containing a nextjs front end and an express back end.

Comment: @MatthewWolman Unfortunately I never managed to figure it out. I ended up hosting the backend separately on a custom domain using Dokku and DigitalOcean, and the frontend on Vercel. 
I had previously deployed a fullstack React app to Heroku, and it was REALLY easy; I assumed it would be the same with Nextjs - I was wrong. 

Not sure how this can get more views, but happy to support in any way I can because I'm still curious and would like to learn how this can be achieved.
Sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Comment: No problem man. I posted a question for this as well and I haven't gotten much back. What I can tell you though is that the newest versions of next.js have a built in routing api that you can access easily. I was going to just split the two like you did but I came across this information and it is really convenient. It is not robust by any means though so it is only viable for not-too-complex api. Here's the official introduction of it by Next.js https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction